# Reading web and replace some words

Tags: android, web

I want to read web pages (not mine and specified) and replace some words with other words in the web page loaded.
For example, let's suppose that there is a webpage that shows string "Hello, World! 07-17-2015". And I want to replace all "07" with "08". Then this page will be shown like this: "Hello, World! 08-17-2015". (There is only a string in this example, but I want to execute at any page)
 I want to do this with Android. Can I make an app with this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a request to get the HTML content of the page (bazillions methods to do it, lots and lots of libraries, or plain `HttpURLConnection`).

Then take that output as `String` and replace what you want:

```
// Your network implementation
String htmlContent = response.data.replaceAll("07", "08");
```

Then use a `WebView` and load this `String` inside it:

```
webView.loadData(htmlContent, "utf-8");
```